# What role does the Apple iTunes server play in Enterprise distribution?

Tags: ios, provisioning

I'm looking into what's involved in distributing an Enterprise App and found this line in Apple's Enterprise App Distribution doc in the section on installing the apps wirelessly:

```
A network configuration that allows the devices to access an iTunes server at Apple
```

What does this mean and why is it necessary? I thought the apps to be installed would be hosted on a company web site, but does this imply otherwise?

TIA

Comment: whats the context here? for enterprise you can have your own server that serves the application to devices...

Comment: Exactly, that's my point -  my question is why do the devices need a network configuration that allows access to an *iTunes server at Apple* when the application is hosted on the Enterprise company's server? According to the documentation the devices need this access, my question is why? Is the documentation misleading?

Comment: perhaps it is, but post a link to the doc, so we can check it out

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html. In the Deploying apps / Installing apps wirelessly section.

Comment: Where are you reading this? in the distribution steps it doesnt say what you are quoting

Comment: In the Deploying apps section (not the Preparing apps for distribution section if that's where your looking), in the sub section titled "Installing apps wirelessly", its the 4th bullet point in the list of Requirements: "A network configuration that allows the devices to access an iTunes server at Apple"

Comment: Im thinking that perhaps it goes to an itunes server to verify the provisiong etc, it just means that the network you are connect to allows for connections to itunes or apple...in short, ull probably be fine..